# login page doesn't work only on aws

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

i recently push my rails4 app on aws. The landing page work (some others too) but the login and subscribe page don't. and they do on localhost.

I have "we're sry blalbla check log" the probleme is i have no information on my log file

just this line :

```
Started GET "/login" for 93.26.170.84 at 2015-08-09 15:10:43 +0000
```

for the request and nothing else.

I am on development environment.

What would you do to find what the problem is ?

thx for your time !

UPDATE :

i coded the login process by myself,

i am using puma

## config/puma.rb

```
workers Integer(ENV['WEB_CONCURRENCY'] || 2)
threads_count = Integer(ENV['MAX_THREADS'] || 5)
threads threads_count, threads_count

preload_app!

rackup      DefaultRackup
port        ENV['PORT']     || 80
environment ENV['RACK_ENV'] || 'development'

on_worker_boot do
  # Worker specific setup for Rails 4.1+
  # See: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/
  # deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server#on-worker-boot
  ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection
end
```

the webserver :

http://52.28.211.67/

UPDATE 2 :

config/development.rb

```
...
  # Show full error reports and disable caching.
  config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
  config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
  config.log_level = :debug
...
```

and i only have a development.log in logs/

still no informations about the probleme :>

Comment: The line that usually appears after that is the result of the routing. Are you using devise for user authentication ?

Comment: Share your web server and rails processor (unicorn?) configurations

Comment: hello thx for your answers ! i update my question

Comment: Make sure your variable for `log_level` is :debug or shows `:fatal` errors. If your frontend shows an error like this, and you don't have more information in your server logs, it probably means you didn't set log level to debug, or that you are actually running in production (RailsEnv is different than Rack_Env). Check `config/environments/development.rb` for log_level

Comment: hello i add the log_level = :debug on my development.rb but no change :/ still no information (cf : UPDATE 2)